Young scientists and mathematicians who made important discoveries despite their advisors' advice to pursue a different course
The following Quanta article tells the story of Luísa Jabbur, a microbial chronobiologist who did research on cyanobacteria. She persuaded her doctoral advisor to conduct an experiment to confirm that these bacteria have the ability to sense the changing of the seasons. Her goal was to find out whether certain proteins that regulate their circadian biorhythms might also be responsible for their responses to seasonal changes. Her advisor initially laughed at the idea. In the end, it turned out she was right and proved her advisor wrong.
Her advisor had a sticky note on their door, that says:

“Progress is made by young scientists who carry out experiments that
old scientists say would not work.”

I wonder whether there are other documented cases of doctoral scientists and mathematicians who went on to make significant discoveries after pursuing a line of research that went against their advisors' wishes, advice, or recommendations. I think this is an interesting subject, because these are good examples of young scientists following their intuition and instincts despite someone with more seniority and authority telling them to do otherwise.

A famous recent example is Yitang Zhang. I do not retell his story here because the Wikipedia article describes it in detail. The story of his relations with his adviser is described here.

Because of the prevalence and severity of link rot, it is good practice to make answers self-contained. Including links to point to one’s sources is fine, but causing one’s answer to be an otherwise stand-alone answer is an investment in its utility to future visitors to SE.

@Paul Tenenbaum: I hope that the links to Wikipedia must be stable. It is quite a complicated story to tell it here in detail.

Although TL;DR, it seems that the extent of “the story of his relations with his advisor” that bears on OP is “I was surprised by Yitang’s next request of working on the Jacobian conjecture as his thesis topic. I felt it was odd to select such a difficult task. After seeing his enthusiasm, I settled on it and did my best to guide him.”
